# can not insert row in a table while data redirecting from parent table to child table in trigger(stored procedure)

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I am using postgres version: *PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit*

Description:

I have one parent table and that parent table has many child tables. I want to redirect the data from parent table to child table (while insertion)

(same As this link: [Example Link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html) ) (example of ice cream company)

I did following things...

```
create table tsttbl1 (id integer, name text);

create table tsttbl1_hour0 (LIKE tsttbl1) INHERITS (tsttbl1);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_tsttbl1_hourbase() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Hi...%', NEW;
    execute 'INSERT INTO ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA|| '.tsttbl1_hour0 values '|| NEW;
    -- INSERT INTO tsttbl1_hour0 values (NEW.*)';
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

create trigger trigger_insert_tsttbl1_hourbase before insert on tsttbl1 FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_tsttbl1_hourbase();
```

Here,

parent table:- tsttbl1

child table:- tsttable1_hour0

Trying to achieve: `insert into tsttbl1 (id, name) values (0,'xyz');` should insert data in **tsttable1_hour0** instead of **tsttbl1**;

But When i tried to insert the row, i am getting like this...

```
ccc=# insert into tsttbl1 (id,name) values (1, 'abc');
LOG:  statement: insert into tsttbl1 (id,name) values (1, 'abc');
NOTICE:  Hi...(1,abc)
ERROR:  column "abc" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO act1.tsttbl1_hour0 values (1,abc)
                                                 ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO act1.tsttbl1_hour0 values (1,abc)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_tsttbl1_hourbase() line 4 at EXECUTE statement
```

Additional Information:

-> This data redirection can also be achieved by rule. But for my case, this insertion is frequently, so rule might be costly compare to trigger...

so i want to achieve this by **trigger** only.

-> if i **un comment** the line "INSERT INTO tsttbl1_hour0 values (NEW.*)'" .. row is inserted **successfully**

-> if i **un comment** the line "INSERT INTO tsttbl1_hour0 values (NEW.id, NEW.name)'" .. row is inserted **successfully**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved in this way...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_tsttbl1_hourbase() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Hi...%', NEW;
    Execute 'set search_path to ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA|| '';
    INSERT INTO tsttbl1_hour0 values (NEW.*);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

instead of **schemaname.tablename**, i have set the **search path** before of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `execute` command is invoking dynamic sql.  It will execute the string that follows, but the syntax pasted together is not correct.  It should be:

```
execute 'INSERT INTO ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA|| '.tsttbl1_hour0 values (' || NEW.id || ', ''' || NEW.name || ''')';
```

That would get that line working, but rather than pasting the line together, with values, binding would be better.  See the [PREPARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-prepare.html#SQL-PREPARE-EXAMPLES) command.

But why use dynamic sql at all rather than the commented line that runs successfully?

Comment: thanks ronin... but the problem is my table has 50 columns... so i cant go with "New.id", "New.name"...    can this possible with New.* ???